Understanding Bayesian Optimal Experiment Design
I read this tutorial on Bayesian Experimentation Design (https://pyro.ai/examples/working_memory.html) and I'm trying to wrap my head around it.
Suppose you have data (X,y).
You're thinking about running an experiment X' (basically another data point), but you can't observe the corresponding y' until you actually observe X', so you do the following to get a sense of how information you will gain:

Fit a model on (X,y) to obtain posterior p = p(y|theta,X)
Plug X' into P to get q, a marginal density q = q(y*|X'), where y* are posterior estimates of y' given X'
Compare p and q using KL

Is this correct?
What I am most confused about is steps 2. At first I thought you were suppose to "update" the model with X' and y*. But I guess that is just for doing an adaptive design?
